# HAProxy returns bad Request with send-proxy-v2

Tags: haproxy, tcp

Haproxy returns 400 with send-proxy-v2 and without send-proxy-v2 it returns proper result.

Config which returns proper result:

```
backend satellites
    balance leastconn
    mode tcp
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    server localhost:10816 127.0.0.1:10816 check

frontend satellitesnoSSL
    bind  :5816
    log global
    mode tcp
    default_backend satellites

    maxconn 60000
    grace 3000
    timeout client 10m
```

Config which returns Http Error 400:

```
backend satellites
    balance leastconn
    mode tcp
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    server localhost:10816 127.0.0.1:10816 check send-proxy-v2

frontend satellitesnoSSL
    bind  :5816
    log global
    mode tcp
    default_backend satellites

    maxconn 60000
    grace 3000
    timeout client 10m
```

I am sending request using urllib2 (a python library) not from browser so it is not the problem of browser.

I need to add add send-proxy-v2 or send-proxy to send the client IP to server.

Answer (score 0):

What is your software which running on **localhost:10816** ? Are you sure is support **Proxy protocol** and it is configured for that ?